# nuxt как правильно обновлять данные передаваемые в компонент?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, компоненты

Есть компонент, модальное окно. При нажатии на кнопку открыть, переменная меняется на true, а при закрытии становится false (через v-if). Суть в том что в компонент, передаются данные, которые меняются при нажатии на разные кнопки, но в компонент новые данные не передаются, как сделать так, что бы при каждом открытии нового модального окна в нём были новые данные.

```
<Component v-if="modal" :data="data" @close="close()" />
```

Переменная modal или true или false. data - меняется, но в компоненте остаются старые данные, как правильно обновлять компонент?

Comment: Попробуйте задать ему атрибут :key="", и обновлять его. А data которую вы передаете в компонент, это вычисляемое свойство?

Comment: Да, туда передаётся объект, и постоянно разный.

Comment: Тогда странно, нужно бы больше кода видеть, буквально недавно делал точно такую же задачу, проблем не встретил

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.